# Single-injection amputation

Tags: law, medical

The Ministry of Peace and Justice is looking for a method to carry out sentences of amputation in a labor or military setting quickly and effectively. The subjects will be workers and military conscripts.

As such, the Ministry demands that the following method is drafted up:

- The condemned is secured by medical assistants or policemen, and a tourniquet is applied to the limb to be amputated.
- An injection of one or multiple agents is applied to the limb.
- After a certain time, the condemned is released to continue with his labor.
- The limb slowly dies and eventually falls off or can be cut off with a food knife. The condemned may be required to apply disinfectant regularly, but should be otherwise able to continue with his daily routine.

Which substances can be used for this? The tourniquet may or may not be removed after the procedure.

Comment: maybe komodo poison/venom? at least the amputation can prevent it from fester it farther. outside of that maybe direct xray thing or radioactive like what happen to edison assistant and several people that consume radioactive.

Answer (score 1):

#### Nothing

You should read up on [elastration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastration), which is the process of removing tails (among, er, other body parts) in a manner almost exactly like you're suggesting. I don't know if it works on tails, but in the case of "other body parts", you can in theory just leave the band (tourniquet) in place until the part dies and allegedly falls off on its own. If you're impatient and your tourniquet works well, just wait anywhere from ten minutes to a few hours for the limb to start dying from loss of blood (and so the nerves are desensitized or dead) and then use a knife/saw/whatever.

#### Liquid nitrogen

If you want the limb to fall off sooner, you could take a page from [Snowpiercer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowpiercer_(TV_series)) and freeze it off. I'm not sure how well this would work, though, since it might be hard to keep the effect from spreading too far.

#### Just about anything

If your goal is to ensure that the victim doesn't just take off the tourniquet and try to save the limb, you could inject it with just about any poison/venom/etc. that will spread to the rest of the body and kill the victim if they let it. (This would give you some built-in drama potential, because there will inevitably be idiots that ignore the warnings and off themselves in this manner.) Of course, as in the previous answer, if you just keep them restrained long enough, the limb will start dying to the point it can't be saved anyway, and necrotic tissues will likely have the same effect.

(Flesh-eating bacteria are an obvious candidate if you're feeling especially sadistic, but I'm not sure those won't be able to spread to the rest of the body. On the other hand, if you're really sadistic, introduce that sort of thing in the fingers/toes so that the victims have to cut off *their own* limbs in order to survive.)

#### Summary

As long as your tourniquet is good enough, it doesn't really matter. The quality/efficacy of your tourniquet, on the other hand, is critical.